# Why chiral symmetry of quark fields has to be associated to flavor, not color?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, quantum-chromodynamics, chirality

Chirality itself arises only from the spinor field, irrelevant with the flavor or color. Why is it so that every time chiral symmetry is discussed, the symmetry group is always decomposed into $SU(N_f)_L \times SU(N_f)_R$ but not into $SU(N_c)_L \times SU(N_c)_R$?

Comment: Because. The book of nature was written this way.

Comment: Gauge transformations are not symmetries. When people discuss symmetries, by definition they only look at flavor transformations. Flavor is a synonym of symmetry. A gauge transformation is not a symmetry. Gauge transformations can act chirally too -- but that is not a chiral symmetry, it's a chiral gauge transformation, which is a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

While the action is invariant under global $SU(N_c)_L\times SU(N_c)_R$ transformations, the quantum theory is not invariant. When a symmetry is gauged, the associated chiral symmetry is what is known as *anomalous*. Color by convention is a gauged symmetry, with gauge field $A_{\mu}^a$, and the chiral current $J^{\mu}_5$ is not conserved

$$\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}_5\sim \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F^a_{\mu\nu}F^a_{\rho\sigma}$$